# Resize tab bar Icons in Xamarin Forms in Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Hi all I am working on a xamarin project and I am adding icons to my tab bar but the images look like this.

I go this to work in IOS but Android is giving me a hard time. I just learned like yesterday It's not just making a custom renderer but I also have to dive into the layout folder and create a custom axml file.

Anyways I followed this really helpful example here on stack overflow and I was able to resize my text but the images are not resizing. Essentially I wanted to make the Text in the Tab to be smaller and the icon to be larger. This was accomplished in IOS but like I mentioned I am struggling on Android.
Below is what I have so far. I think I may be implementing it wrong because some of the terms mentioned were deprecated so I had to implement this with new methods.

[image]

```
public class TabbedPageRendererAndriod : TabbedPageRenderer
    {

        public TabbedPageRendererAndriod(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
 protected override void SetTabIconImageSource(TabLayout.Tab tab, Drawable icon)
    {
        base.SetTabIconImageSource(tab, icon);
        tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.CustomTab);
        var imageView = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon);
        imageView.SetBackground(tab.Icon);
    }   
}
```

**My Layout->CustomTab.axml File**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I now I understand the process but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. I's also like to point out the icon to the left is the one I am trying to make larger. I have also tried adding a larger image to see if It takes but they all default to the size shown in the image

Comment: What's you image size? Does it the same as image of More? The image of More looks right.

Comment: Yeah I wanted them to be larger, I was able to change the icon size on IOS by adding a larger size but on android I've added different sizes and it looks the same. I had begun looking into custom renderers but no luck yet

Comment: In the [sample project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage), there are images sizes you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

this might be a little late, but I ran into the same problem.
I solved it by creating a Custom Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace TabBarIconSize.Droid
{   
    class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // Get TabbedPage's bottomNavigationView
            var bottomNavigationView = (GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.RelativeLayout).GetChildAt(1) as BottomNavigationView;
            
            // Set Icon size
            bottomNavigationView.ItemIconSize = 50;
        }
}
```